# Is there is a way to change the css of ng2-smart-table

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to change the css of ng2-smart-table. I add my screen below. I want to remove the block and apartment box that displays on first row. How to change the apartment column autocomplete box size similar to other fields?

This is my screen
[image: this is my screen]

my .ts file is below,

```
    settings = {columns: {
  block_name: {
    title: 'Block',
    type: 'html',
    editor: {
      type: 'list',
      config: {
        list: this.newblock
      },
    }
  }, cust_name: {
    title: 'Apartment',
    editor: {
      type: 'completer',
      config: {
        completer: {
          data: this.newapart,
          searchFields: 'title',
          titleField: 'title'
        },
      },
    },
  },... }
```

.html file,

```
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <input #search class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." (keydown.enter)="onSearch(search.value)">
    <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" (deleteConfirm)="onDelete($event)"
            (editConfirm)="onSave($event)"
            (createConfirm)="onCreate($event)" ></ng2-smart-table>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends on your html too. Please share your html.

Comment: i added my html file by editing my post.

Comment: https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/762  https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation 'rowClassFunction' perhaps?  Did find on 'CSS' in page. My advice. Try and Google an example on that term. Also... https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/tree/master/src/app/pages/examples - look at the scss and html here,